# Can't connect device via LwM2M to Thingsboard live demo server

Tags: thingsboard, lwm2m

I was following the instructions provided at [Thingsboard LwM2M-API](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/lwm2m-api/).  When trying to connect a Wakaama example client, I get a `Connection creation failed.` log message:

```
$ ./lwm2mclient -h lwm2m.thingsboard.cloud -n NuttX -p 5685 -c
Trying to bind LWM2M Client to port 56830
LWM2M Client "NuttX" started on port 56830
> New Battery Level: 67
value changed!
Opening connection to server at lwm2m.thingsboard.cloud:5685
Connection creation failed.
 -> State: STATE_REGISTERING
Opening connection to server at lwm2m.thingsboard.cloud:5685
Connection creation failed.
 -> State: STATE_REGISTERING
```

Comment: Turns out the Wakaama lwm2mclient defaults to using IPv6, but lwm2m.thingsboard.cloud only supports IPv4.  Solution is to add the `-4` option when calling lwm2mclient

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Wakaama lwm2mclient defaults to using IPv6, but lwm2m.thingsboard.cloud only supports IPv4. Solution is to add the -4 option when calling lwm2mclient